# How to check audit status of creative in facebook ads api

Tags: facebook-ads-api

I want to create new creative and check its audit status in facebook ads api. I want to know whether that creative is approved or rejected. One more question i have , what is the use of adgroup. In documentation they have audit status for adgroup but not for creative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an ad in whole that goes through audit, not only the creative. Adgroup is basically an ad, a combination of creative and targeting. So the audit happens when you create an adgroup.